# Loading XIB Not Working ( Mac )

Tags: objective-c, macos, xib

So my current code (used from another question) looks like this:

```
NSWindowController * wc=[[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"POP"]; 
[wc showWindow:self];
```

The .xib is name POP.xib (Push or Pull).

Please help I would love simple alternatives.

Comment: "Not working" doesn't really tell us anything. HOW is it now working? Are there any error messages? Does it crash?

Comment: No nothing happens. No error messages or anything. check it out github.com/jordanbtahabsim/Auto-Git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok there are some things that you should fix:

1. On your `POP.xib` you must set your `File's Owner` class to `NSWindowController`. Then you should connect its `window` property to the window you want to show (the window in the `xib`).
2. What I found was that because you're using ARC the window shows up for a split second and then disappears. This happens because there is nothing to retain your window controller and the ARC obviously sends a release message to it just after instantiation. So make sure that you are retaining it as well (I just added a `strong` property and set it to the `NSWindowController` we instantiate in the first line and worked fine).

[Here is a corrected project](http://cl.ly/2k3h3Z3U141j3q3n3X3Z)